# How to update data to a specific IDNumber using C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-update

I've been trying to solve this issue I'm having but nothing found on the internet helped. In my c# app, I'm using some forms in order to get some data from a SQL Server database.

In Form1, I have some selected data from the database, and also I have a button called "Edit". When I press "Edit" (which also opens me another form - Form2), I would like to modify some information about that `IDNumber` I want to edit and when I'm trying to update the db I get the following error:

I don't want to insert the same id, I just want to update some info for IDNumber=2 ->

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_Autocare_BF84BD413A6558AF'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Autocare'. The duplicate key value is (2).

I get the following error when I close Form2, in order to go back to Form1 ->

> {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}

Here is my code:

```
private void btnModifica_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       FormulareDeAdaugare.formularAddAutocar frmm = new FormulareDeAdaugare.formularAddAutocar();
       frmm.Text = "Editare";
       frmm.btnAdauga.Text = "Salveaza";
       frmm.txtID.Text = txtID.Text.Trim();
       frmm.cmbTip.SelectedValue = tabaut.Rows[linie][0].ToString();
       frmm.ShowDialog();

        string cs = "Data Source=IS020209;Initial Catalog=TrafficManager;Integrated Security=True";
        string update = "UPDATE Autocare SET IDAutocar = @IDAutocar WHERE IDAutocar = @IDAutocar";

        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
            {
                con.Open();

                {
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(update, con);
                    cmd.Parameters.Clear();
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IDTipAutocar", int.Parse(frmm.cmbTip.SelectedValue.ToString()));
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IDAutocar", int.Parse(frmm.txtID.Text.Trim()));
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    MessageBox.Show("Modificarile au fost efectuate!");
                    con.Close();
                    popaut();
                    poptxt();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception er) { MessageBox.Show(er.Message); }

        }
```

Comment: The error message indicates that you're trying to update `IDAutocar` column with a value that already exists in other row in the same table, hence it recognized as duplicate.

Comment: @har07 - I already know what the error means and I said that before the error blockquote

Comment: Ok, if you knew that SQL Server complained about it, then why you still do that (updating `IDAutocar` with duplicate value)?

Comment: Your update statement doesn't seem to make sense to me. It's basically saying `update autocare set IDAutocar = 1 where IDAutocar = 1`.

Comment: I believe you want to update another column, `IDTipAutocar` maybe, as you have an `SqlCommand` parameter, `@IDTipAutocar`, left unused anywhere in the SQL statement : `string update = "UPDATE Autocare SET IDTipAutocar=@IDTipAutocar WHERE IDAutocar=@IDAutocar";`